# Keep observation if it is within a sequence of 13 numbers of distance 1

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, sequence

For an investing strategy I am looking to calculate momentum returns. Returns are calculated from as the mean of the past 12 to 2 months lag(12)-lag(2).

For these returns I need to clean my dataset and remove every observation that is not in a sequence of 13 observations.

So far I have removed every observation that was on its own:

```
x <- x %>%
  arrange(seriesid, datem) %>%
  group_by(seriesid) %>%
  mutate(A = ifelse(((lead(datem,1)-datem) <=1 | (datem-lag(datem,1)) <=1),1,NA)) %>%
  ungroup()
x <- x[complete.cases(x),
```

And afterwards edited the variable A to show if the distance between lag12 and the actual value or lead 12 and the actual value is 12, incoporating 13 observations.

```
x <- x %>%
  arrange(seriesid, datem) %>%
  group_by(seriesid) %>%
  mutate(A = ifelse(((lead(datem,12)-datem) <=12 | (datem-lag(datem,12)) <=12),1,NA)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Output at the moment

```
date seriesid datem closeret  A
1883-07-28    50102 22603  2.381538e-01 NA
1883-08-25    50102 22604  6.461233e-03 NA
1883-12-29    50102 22608 -3.947368e-02  1
1884-01-26    50102 22609 -2.328767e-01 NA
1884-02-23    50102 22610  0.000000e+00 NA
1884-03-29    50102 22611  3.392857e-01 NA
1884-04-26    50102 22612 -1.733333e-01 NA
1884-05-31    50102 22613  1.612903e-02 NA
1884-06-28    50102 22614 -1.428571e-01 NA
1884-07-26    50102 22615 -2.222222e-01 NA
1884-08-30    50102 22616 -1.428571e-01 NA
1884-09-27    50102 22617  1.111111e-01 NA
1884-10-25    50102 22618  0.000000e+00 NA
1884-11-29    50102 22619 -1.000000e-01 NA
1884-12-27    50102 22620 -3.333333e-01  1
1885-03-28    50102 22623  8.333333e-02 NA
```

As you can see the Column containing A has two 1s 12 steps apart from eachother. Now my goal is to have the values in between there as 1s as well. So that everything in a sequence of at least 13 values one step on datem from eachother are kept and I can remove the NAs later on. I have also tried:

```
x <- x %>%
  arrange(seriesid, datem) %>%
  group_by(seriesid) %>%
  mutate(A = ifelse((lead(A,11)==12&(lead(datem,11)-datem)==11)&(lag(A,1)==12)&(datem-lag(datem,1))==1,12,A)) %>%
  mutate(A = ifelse((lead(A,10)==12&(lead(datem,10)-datem)==10)&(lag(A,2)==12)&(datem-lag(datem,2))==2,12,A)) %>%
  mutate(A = ifelse((lead(A,9)==12&(lead(datem,9)-datem)==9)&(lag(A,3)==12)&(datem-lag(datem,3))==3,12,A)) %>%
  mutate(A = ifelse((lead(A,8)==12&(lead(datem,8)-datem)==8)&(lag(A,4)==12)&(datem-lag(datem,4))==4,12,A)) %>%
  mutate(A = ifelse((lead(A,7)==12&(lead(datem,7)-datem)==7)&(lag(A,5)==12)&(datem-lag(datem,5))==5,12,A)) %>%
  mutate(A = ifelse((lead(A,6)==12&(lead(datem,6)-datem)==6)&(lag(A,6)==12)&(datem-lag(datem,6))==6,12,A)) %>%
  mutate(A = ifelse((lead(A,5)==12&(lead(datem,5)-datem)==5)&(lag(A,7)==12)&(datem-lag(datem,7))==7,12,A)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

However, this changes the previous correct values to be incorrect as well.

Desired output:

```
date seriesid datem closeret  A
1883-07-28    50102 22603  2.381538e-01 NA
1883-08-25    50102 22604  6.461233e-03 NA
1883-12-29    50102 22608 -3.947368e-02  1
1884-01-26    50102 22609 -2.328767e-01  1
1884-02-23    50102 22610  0.000000e+00  1
1884-03-29    50102 22611  3.392857e-01  1
1884-04-26    50102 22612 -1.733333e-01  1
1884-05-31    50102 22613  1.612903e-02  1
1884-06-28    50102 22614 -1.428571e-01  1
1884-07-26    50102 22615 -2.222222e-01  1
1884-08-30    50102 22616 -1.428571e-01  1
1884-09-27    50102 22617  1.111111e-01  1
1884-10-25    50102 22618  0.000000e+00  1
1884-11-29    50102 22619 -1.000000e-01  1
1884-12-27    50102 22620 -3.333333e-01  1
1885-03-28    50102 22623  8.333333e-02 NA
```

Comment: What if there are sequences in `datem` longer than 12? Just insert `1` for every observation, that has a gapless sequence in `datem` preceeding it?

Comment: I want those to kept as well. I have one group that has all observations, there all are set correct. So keep every observation that is in atleast a sequence of 12.

Comment: I mean in a sequence of 13, since lag 12 is 12 observations ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Now we can add some dplyr. The part from before is now in the `sequer` function (I'm terrible at naming).

```
sequer <- function(x) {
  seq <- rle(cumsum(!c(1, diff(x))==1))
  seq$values <- ifelse(seq$lengths >= 13, 1, NA)
  inverse.rle(seq)
}

df %>%
  group_by(seriesid) %>%
  mutate(A = sequer(datem)) -> res

> res
         date seriesid datem     closeret  A
1  1883-07-28    50102 22603  0.238153800 NA
2  1883-08-25    50102 22604  0.006461233 NA
3  1883-12-29    50102 22608 -0.039473680  1
4  1884-01-26    50102 22609 -0.232876700  1
5  1884-02-23    50102 22610  0.000000000  1
6  1884-03-29    50102 22611  0.339285700  1
7  1884-04-26    50102 22612 -0.173333300  1
8  1884-05-31    50102 22613  0.016129030  1
9  1884-06-28    50102 22614 -0.142857100  1
10 1884-07-26    50102 22615 -0.222222200  1
11 1884-08-30    50102 22616 -0.142857100  1
12 1884-09-27    50102 22617  0.111111100  1
13 1884-10-25    50102 22618  0.000000000  1
14 1884-11-29    50102 22619 -0.100000000  1
15 1884-12-27    50102 22620 -0.333333300  1
16 1885-03-28    50102 22623  0.083333330 NA
```

Comment: This works! How do you think it works when switching seriesid though? It could error there